# Get-AzureRmResource : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Tag'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

So I'm totally stumped by this one.

#### The problem

I have a powershell script (a .ps1 file) which at some point does the following:

```
Import-Module AzureRM

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $azureCredentials | out-null
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $azureSubscriptionId -TenantId $azureTenantId | out-null

Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json((Get-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ "env"="dev"}) | Select Name, Location))
```

I run the script in a .NET console app by doing the following:

```
Dim process = New Process() With {.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With {
    .FileName = "powershell.exe",
    .Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file """ & _powershellScriptsPath & "\get-webapps.ps1",
    .UseShellExecute = False,
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
    .RedirectStandardError = True
}}
```

The script works fine on my laptop, whether it's run from the ISE or from the console app.

Then on my desktop, it works fine in ISE but fails in the console app, with the following error message:

```
Get-AzureRmResource : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Tag'.
```

I can't figure this out.

#### Some insights

My `$PSVersionTable` is the same on both computers:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.165                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.165                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

My laptop has version 6.1.0 of the AzureRm module:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRm

Version    Name                                Repository           Description                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
6.1.0      AzureRM                             PSGallery            Azure Resource Manager Module
```

While my desktop has version 6.5.0:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRm

Version    Name                                Repository           Description                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
6.5.0      AzureRM                             PSGallery            Azure Resource Manager Module
```

So there is a difference of versions here but -Tag does exist in 6.1.0 because in Powershell ISE the script does work. And it has to use 6.1.0 since it seems to be the only version that is installed(?).

Also the console app runs the same configuration in both Visual Studios (laptop/desktop) (at least as far as I can tell). Notably it's compiled as AnyCPU and runs in 32bit on both computers.

Comment: what prevents you from updating azurerm to 6.5.0 just to be sure? also, you can add get-command get-azurermresource -full to your console app and examine the output

Comment: Your command has pointed the issue I think - it says 6.2.0 when run from the ISE (when the script works) but 5.5.2 when run from the console app (when it fails). I assume the -Tag parameter did not exist in 5.5.2. The question now being - where does it get 5.5.2 from and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-5.7.0) it seems like `-tag` is missing pre 6.0.0 version of AzureRm. That is the root cause of the issue identified by:

```
get-command get-azurermresource -full
```

workaround would be to upgrade that version. you can find where the module is by doing:

```
get-module azurerm  | select modulebase
```

ps. another workaround would be to use odata query:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=tagname eq 'something'"
```

Comment: Ok so on the "faulty" computer, the console app is loading the module from `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\5.7.0`, for some reason. Why would the same script runs different versions of the module when run from the ISE or (same version of) .NET?

Comment: I have tried adding -MinimumVersion to the Import-Module command, but the result is `Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureRM' with version '6.5.0' was not loaded because no valid module file was ` (also tried 6.0.0). It seems like Visual Studio / .NET is not aware of the 6.5.0 version that is installed and used by default by ISE and I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: i guess its installed only for your user?

Comment: I have installed it by running Install-Module -Name AzureRm on both computers and as instructed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.5.0. So that would be weird but how would I check if it's installed for my user only? That being said, all that Windows stuff slightly gets over my head so to circumvent this I like the idea of the -ODataQuery workaround... just need to figure out how to also test for the value of the tag (your example returns me all resources with a given tag but doesn't look at the tag value).

Comment: Ok well I could not find any official documentation on this because Microsoft but I have figured it out: `Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "\`$filter=tagname eq 'env' and tagvalue eq 'dev'"`returns me what I want. I have no idea why my Visual Studio won't load the 6.5.0 module but at this point I have a script that returns what I need and runs on older version of the AzureRm module so I am fine with it! Thanks for your help!